.Net MAUI Community Toolkit Popup margin
I am trying to achieve the same result from a popup window as in xamarin.forms. For the main popup layout:
Grid gButtons = new Grid()
{
    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill,
    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill,
    BackgroundColor = backgroundColor,
    Margin = new Thickness(55, 0, 55, 0),
    ColumnDefinitions = new ColumnDefinitionCollection()
    {
        new ColumnDefinition(){ Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star)},
    },
    RowDefinitions = new RowDefinitionCollection()
    {
        new RowDefinition(){ Height = new GridLength(0, GridUnitType.Auto)},
        new RowDefinition(){ Height = new GridLength(0, GridUnitType.Auto)},
    },
};
***
Content = gButtons;

Margin has no effect on window. I can't set hardcoded sizes on popup, because it's bad practice (IMHO). How do I make the margins work?
CommunityToolkit.Maui ver 9.0.2
Platform: Android
.Net ver 8.0

To help others better reproduce this question, please include in your question the .NET version, the CommunityToolkit version and the platform you use.

You may try wrapping the Grid with a StackLayout,
StackLayout stacklayout = new StackLayout();
Grid gButtons = new Grid()
...
stacklayout.Children.Add(gButtons);
Content = stacklayout;

Then the margin should work for the Grid.
You may also try setting the WidthRequest or HeightRequest for the StackLayout to fit the size.
